# How can I remove this switch case when the React Element name is always the same as the switch variable?

Tags: reactjs

What is a more succinct way of writing this. The pageType is always the same as the React element name and I should be able to do away with the switch statement.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import Standard from './Standard/Standard';
import Banners from './Banners/Banners';

export default class ProductPages extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    pageType: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  render() {

    let ProductPage;
    switch (this.props.pageType) {
      case 'Standard':
        ProductPage = <Standard products={products}/>;
        break;
      case 'Banners':
        ProductPage = <Banners products={products}/>;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('pageType is not valid');
    }

    return ProductPage;
  }
}
```

Comment: As `Standard` and `Banners` are React components not just simple `Elements` you need do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26495/

Comment: or with `React.createElement` - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26496/

Comment: Nice solution! Post an answer for an upvote :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `Standard` and `Banners` are `React` components not just simple `Elements` you need to do something like this,

```
const Components = { Standard, Banners };

class ProductPages extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const ProductPage = Components[this.props.pageType];
    return <ProductPage products={ [] } />
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26495/)

or with `React.createElement`

```
const Components = { Standard, Banners };

class ProductPages extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(Components[this.props.pageType], { products: [] })
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26496/)

however, as you can see here the main idea to save references to `Components` and then use it. You can read more about this case on [React GitHub issues](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3365)

**Note**

```
const Components = { Standard, Banners };
```

is new ECMAScript 6 feature that called [Object Literal Property Value Shorthand](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand.html)

Comment: When will one work and other wouldn't ? I am facing an issue where using <ProductPage/> doesn't work, but using {React.createElement(ProductPage)} works fine.